# Visual Studio 2013 debugging access issue with breakpoints

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints, access-denied

I've been having an issue with debugging my C++ programs recently in Visual Studio 2013. Normally my programs will run fine, however, when I include a breakpoint at the end of my code in order to keep the console open, I will have to manually stop the debugging of the program afterwards (Shift + F5), which will consistently cause an error saying "The debugger was unable to terminate one or more processes: [4912] .exe: Access is denied. The debugger may be unstable now. It is recommended that you save all files and exit." If I go on to continue coding and then compile again later, it will fail to compile with the error that access is denied with fatal error LNK1168, saying it cannot open the .exe for writing. This only happens when I include a breakpoint in my code, so I'm wondering if there's a fix for this, or something that I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: that linker error means that your exe is still running. therefore the file of your exe is still locked, and as a result the linker cannot overwrite the file with a new exe.